# Arbitrary length vectors in Sage

Tags: python, sage

I want to generate a vector of arbitrary values with length dependent on a variable.

What I have that works:

```
var('x')

n = 5
A = [var('a{}'.format(i)) for i in range(n)]

for i in range(n):
    assume(0 <= A[i])
assume(x <= max(A))

product_fn = prod(A)
integral = integrate(product_fn, x)
print(integral)
```

What I want (does not work):

```
var('x')
var('g')

A = [var('a{}'.format(i)) for i in range(g)]

for i in range(len(A)):
    assume(0 <= A[i])

assume(x <= max(A))

product_fn = prod(A)
integral = integrate(product_fn, x)
print(integral)
```

```
TypeError: unable to convert g to an integer
```

I understand that this is due to the `var` being different from python variables, but I'm new to Sage and don't know how to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question.  Namely, can one make a sequence of symbolic variables, the length of which is dependent upon the value of another symbolic variable?

However, if you wanted to do that using anything directly Python-based (which your list comprehension and `range` are), it would be doomed to failure.  Python wants to know how long your list is when you make it.  Your error comes because the `range` function needs integers to even work, whereas `g` here is a symbolic variable whose value could be, well, anything else symbolic or numeric in a given expression.  (What would `range(2.11001)` return?)

To the practical side, is it possible to delay your creation of these variables until you actually know what `g` is supposed to be, and then use your first solution?  (Perhaps in a function?)